# How do I set the starting value of the y axis to 80 and increment it my 1 or 0.5 range

Tags: c#, windows, charts, linechart

I tried using the code below

```
//set interval of y axis to 0.5

chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 0.5;

//how do i set the starting value to be 80....and the max value to be 90
```

Comment: [Golly that was hard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.maximum(v=vs.110).aspx)   _"For my next trick"_ -  Eddie, the shipboard computer

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done right from the properties window -> ChartAreas->Axes->Y (Value) Axis->Minimum / Maximum

```
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = 90;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = 80;
```